# Specifying no return in a conditional statement does not result in an error

Tags: typescript

Can anyone explain the reason why Typescript doesn't throw an error for this block of code?

```
const getStatus = (score: number): ReportStatus => {
  if (score >= 2.2) {
    new ReportStatus(ReportStatusEnum.Excellent);
  } else if (score < 2.2 && score > 0) {
    return new ReportStatus(ReportStatusEnum.NeedsAdjustment);
  } else {
    return new ReportStatus(ReportStatusEnum.NeedsImmediateAttention);
  }
};
```

On the first `if` statement there is no return specified, even though the function's return type is explicitly declared as `ReportStatus`, which itself is a class.

Comment: What error are you expecting?

Comment: Do you have `strictNullChcks` and/or `noImplicitReturns` turned on?

Comment: @msanford a compiler error.

Comment: @NicholasTower no, I haven't changed them on tsconfig.

Comment: If they're both off, then that's the expected behavior. With `strictNullChecks` off, a return type of `ReportStatus` implicitly means `ReportStatus | null | undefined`. So returning `undefined` from this function is legal. And with `noImplicitReturns` off, returning `undefined` can be done implicitly, by having no return statement.

Comment: @NicholasTower That must be it! Thank you. But I wonder why `strictNullChecks` is not turned on by default. Honestly, It's exactly the type of error I'd expect from Typescript.

Comment: Btw, if you turn on the `strict` config that will automatically include `strictNullChecks`

Comment: "strict" is on by default these days, so if he didn't change them, i don't know why they'd be off.